# Send nested json data with get method using axios

Tags: javascript, json, get, nested, axios

I am trying to send a nested json data with get method using axios, but the problem is that the backend considers the children as a string.

```js
const TOKEN = "token"
const config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': TOKEN,
    },
    data: {},
    params: {
        "page_id": 1,
        "filter": {
            "search": "name"
        }
    }
};
axios.get("http://localhost/api/pages", config)
```

What I get if I want to print `filter` in backend:

```
"{"search": "name"}"
```

Comment: `config.params.filter`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have two options:

1- The first option is to decode the string you receive to json.

e.g.

---`json_decode()` in php

--- `JSONObject()` in java

--- `JSON.parse()` in nodejs

or any other method depending on your backend language...

2- The second option is to send your object in this format:

```js
params: {
    "page_id": 1,
    "filter[search]": "name"
}
```

And pay attention not to put `search` in quotes!

Comment: for option 2, it throws error: Invalid character found in the request target

Answer (score 0):

You can use `req.query` on the server side:

```
function get(req, res, next) {
  const { filter } = req.query;
  console.log(filter);
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a `JSON.parse()` of your `Request.query.filter`. **Note that** *Request* should be the request variable in your backend.